# Android to PHP Server No data received

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send JSON String from android application to PHP server. Although i didn't implement any reasonable coding on server side but it is enough to see what coming. Let me show you my Android code and PHP code. Problem is i am not getting anything on server. No response at all. I actually verified this program with Python code on local server and i received the intended output but on PHP nothing. There must be something that i am missing as i am new to PHP.

Here is **ANDROID** code: This is running in a different thread.

```
public void onSync(View v) throws JSONException, IOException {

        //This will call onSync function.

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SYNC);

    }


    protected void onSync_() {

        String json = null;
        try {
            json = database.getAllAsJSONString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("", "Could not convert to JSON", e);
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            byte[] jsonBytes = json.getBytes("UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL("http://androidapplicati.base.pk");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(jsonBytes.length);
            urlConnection
                    .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    String.valueOf(jsonBytes.length));

            out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            out.write(jsonBytes);
            out.flush();
            urlConnection.getInputStream().read();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("", "Error posting data(1)", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", "Error posting data(2)", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("", "Error closing stream", e);
            }
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

Here is **PHP** code.

```
<?php 

print_r($_REQUEST);

var_dump($_REQUEST);

?>
```

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` please have a look at AsyncTask to make HTTP Calls

Comment: I am calling this function inside different thread. So this call is not inside main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not sending the data as key-val pairs
so its not stored in `$_REQUEST[]` array
so i think you need to read it in a different way, i faced this before,

also, you can't see the output of the PHP page,
so either you read the http-call response and log it at your mobile app
or you save the value in a text file at server, so you can know whats going on,

try this in your php:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
writeToFile('myfile.txt',$data);
```

also , its good to use [HttpClient](http://hmkcode.com/android-internet-connection-using-http-get-httpclient/)

Comment: This is what i am sending in request. [{"title ":"First entry ","address ":"Street 14, city, country"}]

Comment: Thanks man it did solve my problem was stuck there for few hours. I was close to throw my mobile and than assault people who made this server.